# "Link SDK Frameworks only" linker option causes compile error in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.essentials

I am using Xamarin.Essentials in my project. If I have linker option as "Link SDK Frameworks only", I am getting the below error.

```
MTOUCH: Error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void Xamarin.Essentials.ShareRequestBase::set_Title(System.String)', referenced from the method 'System.Void *ViewModel/<<get_ExportCommand>b__52_0>d::MoveNext()' in 'Xamarin.Essentials, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. (MT2101) (*.iOS)
```

If linker option is "Don't link" It compiles without error. May I know how can I resolve the error as "Don't link" linker option increases the app size considerably.

Comment: What version of essentials are you using?

Comment: the version is 1.5.1

Comment: it occurs in 1.4.0 also

Comment: Can you please share us a basic sample to reproduce this issue or share some code you use? I installed Xamarin.Essentials with latest version in a new project and build successfully.